# How to Configure Wine on Raspberry Pi Runnung Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, 21.10

I want to run some windows programs on my raspberry pi with ubuntu 21.04; when I attempt to install wine, this happens[image]

See that error code at the bottom of that terminal output?  That is the problem I am trying to work out.  I ran `dpkg --configure wine64-development` an I get a similar error here.[image]  It also wanted me to `configure libwine-development`, and I tried that too.  It still is giving me problems as you can see.  I tried to reinstall wine, but the same problems happened.

Comment: I saw the lie referring to zlib, but `apt install zlib` doesn't install it, so how do I install it?

Comment: While I don't know how to fix this particular issue in Ubuntu, [Twister OS](https://twisteros.com/) has out of the box support for emulating x86 Windows programs (with Wine and Box86) in Raspberry Pi. In case you intend to run Windows programs on RPi, consider using it instead. Note that Twister OS is not supported on this site (as it is not an official flavor of Ubuntu). *I am **NOT** affiliated with Twister OS*.

Comment: The install fails because you have encountered [Debian Bug #991384](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=991384). If you *really* want to develop using Wine, you must install from source. Sorry. If you don't want to develop using Wine, then you must apt-mark the `libwine-development` package to 'remove' or 'purge' so that apt stops trying to install it. Normal users don't need that package to run Wine.

Comment: So do you have a solution, or are you telling me it is impossible?  `libwine-development` is not on my system.

Comment: If you have a solution, post it as an answer!

Comment: Actually 2 (two) solutions were already given in the comment just above yours.

Comment: In that case, I don't know how use the solutions provided.